# Simplest way to send ether

Tags: transactions, ether

I have a public and private keys of my account and need to send it to another account. I'm really new to this and both it a year ago and now want to sell it on exchange. So I need a really simple way to transfer funds from one account to another without getting much deeper into technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to install MetaMask as a browser plugin - https://metamask.io/

use metamask import account feature to add your account and then you can simply transfer ether from your account to other.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download a wallet, such as [Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases). You will then need to import your private key, to be able to send transactions from your account. After this you should have the ability to send available funds to any account from the wallet you have downloaded.